# Deploying to Azure from Github and Token

Tags: laravel, azure

I'm trying to deploy Laravel 5.2 to Azure from Github.  I keep getting this deploy error.  I'm not sure how to add the token.  I created one at my github account and added it with: composer config github-oauth.github.com ".  This added the auth.json with the token information, but still no luck when trying to deploy.  I get the same error.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Command: D:\home\SiteExtensions\ComposerExtension\Hooks\deploy.cmd
Install Dependencies with Composer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
  - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.21.0)
    Downloading

Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/briannesbitt/Carbon/zipball/7b08ec6f75791e130012f206e3f7b0e76e18e3d7, please create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+RD00155DB2046E+2016-02-21+1233
to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "D:\home\site\repository/auth.json" for future use by Composer.

Token (hidden): No token given, aborting.
You can also add it manually later by using "composer config github-oauth.github.com <token>"
Command 'starter.cmd D:\home\SiteExt ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 60 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually enter the command in azure web app console.
yes before command execution you have to add composer extension to your app from azure extensions.

type below command: composer config github-oauth.github.com

you can generate personal token from github seetings.

P.S let us know if you have any easy method to do so